# DOMElement::setAttribute not working php

Tags: php, xml

I've an xml file containing tag like this.

```
<server>
  <conversation ip="12.0.0.1" email="none">
     <chat userstatus="1" adminstatus="2" username="admin">muja</chat>
  </conversation>
</server>
```

Now I want to update the email attribute of the conversation tag.
When I use `$conv->getAttribute("email")` it echo's me the correct result i.e none.But if I try to set it using `$conv->setAttribute("email","abc")` it does not update the value.
Here's what I am doing.

This is the GetClientConversation():

```
private function GetClientConversation()
{
    foreach($this->conversation as $convTag)
    {
        if($convTag->getAttribute("ip") == $this->clientip)
        {
            return $convTag;
        }
    }

    return "noConversation";
}
```

This function returns me the correct conversationTag that I needed.

And i get these conversationsTags array using

```
  $this->conversation=$this->xmlDom->getElementsByTagName("conversation");
```

Edit:

```
public function GetConversation()
{
        $conv=$this->GetClientConversation();
        if($conv!="noConversation")
        {
            if($conv->getAttribute("email")=="none")   
            {
                $conv->setAttribute("email","abc");    // -- Here
                return json_encode($this->RetrieveConversation($conv));
            }
            else if($conv->getAttribute("email")==$this->adminEmail)
            {
                return json_encode($this->RetrieveConversation($conv));
            }
            else
            {
                return "Admin Already Chatting";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->CreateNewConversation();
            return "no";
        }
}
```

This is the code from where I am trying to set the attribute.

Comment: Can you show the code in context where you're attempting `setAttribute()`?

Comment: I've checked both the ip and email tag both are working for `getAttr` but not for `setAttr`.

Comment: But what about `RetrieveConversation()`? How is it saving the XML?

Comment: ohk I got it. very dumb mistake. The problem is not with retrieveXml it is with saveXml I was not calling the saveXml function thats why it was not doing it.Thnx for pointing out indirectly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have correctly used `setAttribute()`.

You are retrieving your XML and passing the string back to `json_encode()`.  However, if the `RetrieveConversation()` method has not correctly called `saveXML()` prior to returning the string, your modifications will not be available in the output XML string.  Be sure you have called `saveXML()`.